# php not returning values to ajax success call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem where I am wishing to return values from a php page when they are submitted via Ajax from a jquery serialize event. I have set the submit button value to 'Add Box' and I am checking against this using isset, to see if this value has been posted. I know that the value is being posted from firebug, but nothing is coming back to the #BA_addbox div to display. Where have I gone wrong. Thanks

Submit button html

```
<input class="AddBoxSubmitButton" type="submit"  id="submit" name="submit" value="Add Box" />
```

php code
boxesadd.php

```
    <?php

    $box = $_POST['BA_box'];    

    $array = split('[,]', $_POST['BA_box']);

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
             foreach ($array as $box) {

               if ($box == '')
                 {
                    echo '<div style="background-color:#ffa; padding:2px; color:#ff0000;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal">' . 'You must select a box for intake' . '</div>';
                 }

               else

                 {
                $sql = "SELECT item FROM `lo` WHERE item = '$box'";
                $result = runSQL($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0)

                {
                    echo '<div style="background-color:#ffa; padding:2px; color:#ff0000;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal">' . 'Box: ' . $box . '  is already in the archive. No duplicates' . '</div>';

                }

              else
                {
                //insert into db;
                echo '<div style="background-color:#ffa; padding:2px; color:#33CC33;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal">' . "Box: " . $box . " " . "Successfully added to the archive" . '</div>';
                //$sql = "INSERT INTO `lo` (service, activity, company, address, department, user, destroydate, date, item, new) VALUES ('$service', '$activity', '$company', '$address', '$dept', '$authorised', '$destdate', NOW(), '$box', 1)";


             }
           }
        }   
     }
?>
```

jquery code

```
$(function(){         
        $('#BA_boxform input:submit').on('click', function () {
        var formdata = $('#BA_boxform').serialize() + '&submit=' + $(this).val();
         //alert(formdata);
         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/domain/admin/requests/boxes/boxesadd.php",
           data: formdata,
           dataType: 'html',
           success: function(msg){
               //$("#confirm_department").hide();

               /*
               var $dialog = $('<div id="dialog"></div>')
               .html('Your intake was successfully submitted and will be viewable in the reporting area.<br /><br />Thank you.');
               $dialog.dialog({
               autoOpen: true,
               modal: true,
               title: 'Box intake submission successfull',
               width: 400,
               height: 200,
               draggable: false,
               resizable: false,
               buttons: {
               Close: function() {
               $( this ).dialog( "close" );
               }
               }
               });
               */
               //alert('You have succesfully submitted your ' + msg.company + ' report. Thank you.');
               console.log(msg);
               $("#BA_addbox").html(msg);

               //$("#formImage .col_1 li").show();
               $("#BA_boxform").get(0).reset();
               //$("#boxaddform").hide();
          }
       });
         return false;
     });
});

// End function to submit box intake form
```

Comment: First of all, split is deprecated, use `explode(',', $_POST['BA_box']);` instead. Second, it's not returning anything? Does the JS error console say anything?

Comment: you said the call is fired as you can see from firebug. Is there any response shown using the firebug. is it appearing as red?.you can see the response using firebug.

Comment: When i do alert(formdata) I can see all the correct values are being posted. There are no error messages in console only (an empty string) and nothing in red in the net tab either

Comment: Just  a thought, is it addboxes.php or boxesadd.php ?

Comment: @rusin it is boxesadd.php. typo on my part. thanks